# ID my bmx please

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

I want to sell my bmx, however when I was younger I must have thought that it was clever taking all the stickers off.

Now I don't know what brand the bmx itself actually is.

If someone could help me I'd be very grateful, if I remember rightly I bought it around 2011 if that's any help.

Comment: It looks blue and fairly generic.

Comment: For sale: blue BMX, good condition. Bought new in 2011 and not ridden that much. Just one owner and no obvious damage. Not stolen. See photos. $50 obo.

Comment: Yep, it's blue.  A decent quality bike (much better than your typical BSO), but nothing distinctive about it.

Comment: Did you buy it for yourself or did someone give it to you ?  Try searching out any paperwork from that date (you would have needed to keep them for warranty service in the first couple years.)  Or if you can recall from where it was purchased, ask there.

Comment: Looks like there's a head badge, a picture of that could be useful.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like a Fit to me https://fitbikeco.com/  But I can't be certain.

Comment: Can you please use Edit to add supporting information?  Whats a Fit?  Try and provide a photo that shows how they are similar.   Such a short and unsubstantiated answer needs to be expanded to be useful.

Comment: I've also guessed at the URL you were referencing.  If that's not right please use Edit to add the whole address.